# SQL command to find the repetitive day?

Tags: sql

on which day  most people login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DAYNAME()` like that.

```
SELECT DAYNAME([column_with_date])
FROM [table] 
GROUP BY DAYNAME([column_with_date])
order by count(DAYNAME([column_with_date])) desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to find max frequency

```
select date,max(freq) 
from (SELECT date,count(date) as freq from TableName
group by date);
```

this will give the Date and max frequency of that date in column.

or you can use below code

```
SELECT date,count(date) as freq from TableName
group by date
limit 1;
```

**here i'm assuming date as column name.**

Comment: it shows me error name as every derived table has its own alias